# I cannot get a basic sphere to render

Tags: javascript, three.js

I've been following this tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6oFvqLfRnsU in order to render basic shapes in three.js. At 18:20 he gets a sphere to show up in his scene.

```
  var scene = new THREE.Scene();

  var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(75, window.innerWidth/window.innerHieght, 0.1, 1000);
    camera.position.z = 5;
  var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({antialias: true});

  renderer.setClearColor("#e5e5e5");
  renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);

  window.addEventListener('resize', () => {
      renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
      camera.aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
      camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
  })

  document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

  var geometry = new THREE.SphereGeometry(1,10,10);
  var material = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({color: 0xFFCC00});
  var mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);

  scene.add(mesh);

  renderer.render(scene, camera);
```

My scene seems to be rendering since I have the light gray background but I can't get the black sphere to show up

Comment: As you're using `THREE.MeshLambertMaterial()` you need a light source in your scene.

Comment: Your code looks fine. Are you getting any errors in your browser's console?

Comment: @Marquizzo Im not getting any errors in the console

Comment: @prisoner849 I added a light source and rerendered and i still dont see it

Answer (score 1):

There was a typo in your code:
`var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(75, window.innerWidth/window.innerHieght, 0.1, 1000);`

`window.innerHieght` must be `window.innerHeight`

```js
var scene = new THREE.Scene();

var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(75, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.1, 1000);
camera.position.z = 5;
var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({
  antialias: true
});
renderer.setClearColor("#e5e5e5");
renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

window.addEventListener('resize', () => {
  renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
  camera.aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
  camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
})



var light = new THREE.DirectionalLight(0xffffff, 0.5);
light.position.setScalar(10);
scene.add(light);
scene.add(new THREE.AmbientLight(0xffffff, 0.5));

var geometry = new THREE.SphereGeometry(1, 10, 10);
var material = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({
  color: 0xFFCC00
});
var mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);

scene.add(mesh);

renderer.render(scene, camera);
```

```css
body {
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://threejs.org/build/three.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Good eye! I read it up and down twice and couldn't find any errors.

Comment: @Marquizzo I just bump into that issue with typos time to time when coding :D

Comment: Good eye. Also for OP, in case you didn't notice, you can run prisoner849s snippet by clicking "show code snippet" and clicking "run".